# Font-face & Wordpress: Font not showing some UTF-8 characters it should support

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-face, typeface

I am working on a site: http://www.blissfulage.sk/ (wordpress)

and using Bebas Neue typeface for headlines (via css font-face). As you can see, some of the characters seem not to be supported, which would be normal, but Bebas Neue should support them (test: http://www.fonts2u.com/bebasneue.font?ptext=s%C3%BA%C5%A5a%C5%BE&submit=Submit ). The funny thing is the problem occurs only for some characters (the ones with " ˇ "). What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

otf file from fonts2u supports, but your converted files (I've tested ttf) not. Try to use converter that supports Latin Extended sets.

Comment: Thanks! Their font-face kit still doesn´t support 4 characters I need, but at least I know this is the way to go. So I will either use a different converter, like you suggested, or .otf instead of .ttf.